# Jquery carousel append new image

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm working on a jquery carousel. You can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/2/

Click on populate, then click increase a few times. It gets all glitchy.

The following function works when I'm not trying to append a new image back into the carousel Click on decrease button to see it work properly. What is the proper way to stick an image back into the image carousel?

```
function slide_img_left(){

    $('.left_slot').animate({
        opacity: 0,
        left: '-=50px'
    },300);

    $('.middle_slot').animate({
        left: '-=50px'
    },300, function(){
        $('.middle_slot').attr('class','left_slot');
        $('.right_slot').attr('class','middle_slot');
        alert(imgArr[c][0]);
        $("#basic_div").append(imgArr[c][0]);           // This line causes the problem but I don't know the correct way to put the new image in.
    });

    $('.right_slot').animate({
        left: '-=50px'
    },300);

}
```

Comment: I should add that the images are all stored in an array called imgArr which is being cycled through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined variable `c` in a function and then using it in anther function giving rise to runtime error(`c is not defined`). I have defined it in the outer scope so that it gets available to all the functions using it.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/1/

Comment: Thanks @ShankarSangoli for your help. I've made your changes and It does appear that the images are being added to the array but they do not appear when I try to append them to the div... Do I have to do something with the css of the new image or give it some attribute with jquery to make it recognize this as a new child? .append works in the ready function but not in the function to slide those images over? I've updated it... [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/2/_)